# how to get dynamically selected id which is fetched from for loop in HTML table using flask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I have fetched the records from database and used for loop to show the data in HTML table with three links. Now I want to read the particular selected data id. example if I select 25 select how can i get that id in JavaScript or jQuery.

html

```
<tbody id="myTable1">
          {% for user_qa in tea %}
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" id="q_no">{{ user_qa.qa_id }}</th>
            <td>{{user_qa.qa_by}}</td>
            <td><b>{{user_qa.qa_crop}}</b></td>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="m_id" id="m_id" value="{{user_qa.qa_id}}">
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="" name="question" id="question">{{user_qa.Question}}</textarea></td>
            <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="" name="answer" id="answer">{{user_qa.Answer}}</textarea></td>
            <td>
              <a href="/master_update/{{user_qa.qa_id}}" class="btn btn-warning" id="button_size" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit{{user_qa.qa_id}}">Update</a><br><br>
              <a href="/master_approve/{{user_qa.qa_id}}" class="btn btn-warning button_size" id="approve_it">Approve</a><br><br>
              <a href="/delete_master/{{user_qa.qa_id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure For Delete?')" id="button_size">Delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
{%endfor%}
    </tbody>
```

javascript
Here I am getting the last records id when I click any records, how can I get particular id if I click on that.

```
<script>
      $("#myTable1").on('click', '#approve_it', function (e) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        var question_id = document.getElementById("q_no");
        console.log("question_id",question_id)
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use same ids for mutliple elements instead use class . Then , inside your event handler get `q_no` value using `$(this).closest('tr').find('.q_no')` this will give you closest tr from `approve_it` then using `find()` will get that particular `td`.

***Demo Code***:

```js
$("#myTable1").on('click', '.approve_it', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  //use closest and find
  var question_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.q_no').text();
  console.log("question_id", question_id)
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="myTable1">

    <tr>
      <!--use class-->
      <th scope="row" class="q_no">1</th>
      <td>somethingsd</td>
      <td><b>Y</b></td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="m_id"  value="1">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="" name="question">somthin..?</textarea></td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="" name="answer">good</textarea></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/master_update/{{user_qa.qa_id}}" class="btn btn-warning button_size" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit{{user_qa.qa_id}}">Update</a><br><br>
        <a href="/master_approve/{{user_qa.qa_id}}" class="btn btn-warning button_size approve_it">Approve</a><br><br>
        <a href="/delete_master/{{user_qa.qa_id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs button_size" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure For Delete?')">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="q_no">2</th>
      <td>somethingsd</td>
      <td><b>B</b></td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="m_id"  value="2">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="" name="question">somthin..?</textarea></td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="" name="answer">good</textarea></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/master_update/{{user_qa.qa_id}}" class="btn btn-warning button_size" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit{{user_qa.qa_id}}">Update</a><br><br>
        <a href="/master_approve/{{user_qa.qa_id}}" class="btn btn-warning button_size approve_it">Approve</a><br><br>
        <a href="/delete_master/{{user_qa.qa_id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs button_size" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure For Delete?')">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop generates the same "q_no" for all (id="q_no") rows. Just image if you have multiple html elements with the same id in DOM.

To generate unique id of the html element try below :

```
<a href="/master_approve/{{user_qa.qa_id}}" class="btn btn-warning button_size" id="approve_it{{user_qa.qa_id}}" data-qaId="{{user_qa.qa_id}}">Approve</a><br><br>

id="approve_it{{user_qa.qa_id}}"  : This will generate unique id
data-qaId="{{user_qa.qa_id}}"  : This will add new attribute in html element as qa_id
```

Now in the click event you know the eleme has been clicked (this). Get the data-qaId attribute value of clicked element which is your question id

Hope it helps

Comment: I have done this method i am not able to get the id. I need to change the event calling method ?    I added in the event method       var question_id = $("#approve_it").attr("data-qaId");

Comment: Add attribute     data-qaId="{{user_qa.qa_id}}"  in approve button.   Get a value of quetionId in click event before you remove Tr using   -  var questionID = this.getAttribute("data-Id");